# How do I view an image in Visual Studio 2022 when coding?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, image-editing

In Visual Studio 2019, image files in my solution opened in a image viewer when developing.  Very useful when I am coding maths on CAD shapes, using a split window to show the image with dimension names beside the code I am writing.

In visual Studio 2022 the image files (png in my case) open in the resource editor, with another split window, that I cannot resize.

VS 2022 - more useful for working on the image
[image: VS 2022 - image opened in resource editor]

VS 2019 - much more useful for working on the code
[image: VS 2019 - image opened in viewer]

I have tried the open with r-click menu without finding a simple viewer within visual studio.

I am expecting that there is a way to simply view the image in the project instead of it opening in the editor